# AngularJS unclear code execution

Tags: angularjs, html

Having a UserService with the following code:

```
this.result = function(credentials)
    {
        $http.post('http://localhost:8080/user/login', credentials).then(function (status) {
            return status;
        });
    };
```

And a LoginController with the following code:

```
$scope.doLogin = function()
    {
        var result = UserService.result($scope.credentials);
        alert(result);
    };
```

Why does the alert window popup **before** the **POST** is done/shown in firebug console, giving me an `undefined` message instead of a HTTP status code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `$http` is an async operation. And so, it immediately returns a promise and then executes the handler at a later time. `return status;` returns the value to whoever handles the result.

In your case, `this.result` function doesn't return anything - it just executes the `$http` call, and so the `result` is undefined. Immediately afterwards the program executes `alert(result)`.

The correct way is to follow through with promises until the end, and assign the value in the promise handler.

```
this.result = function(credentials)
{
    return  // return the promise
       $http.post('http://localhost:8080/user/login', credentials);
}
```

Then, in the controller, handle the promise:

```
$scope.doLogin = function(){
    UserService.result($scope.credentials)
       .then(function(result){
          alert(result);
       });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because $http is asynchronous. The alert would need to be in a callback function or in the promise itself. For example:

```
// Service
this.result = function(credentials) {
    return $http.post('http://localhost:8080/user/login', credentials);
};

// Controller
UserService.result($scope.credentials).then(function (status) {
    alert(status);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it's asynchronous. When you call UserService.result it will send the request and then return. Then you immediately do the alert.

Instead you should do the alert when the request completes, by returning the promise and putting your alert in .then().

Answer (score 1):

Your function returns undefined (because it's not set to return anything). Don't be confused by what you return in the callback function - it never goes "out" to the original function.

The easiest fix is to return the whole $http call object (which returns a promise), and do the then() part in the controller.